# Azure CLI Stop/Start All continuous webjobs script

Tags: bash, azure, github-actions, azure-cli

I'm reviewing the Microsoft Azure CLI docs for [start continuous webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/webjob/continuous?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_webjob_continuous_start) and it doesn't have the option to stop all webjobs. I am only able to stop one job at a time.
The command is being used in [Azure CLI Action for Github](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-cli-action)

Where this issue comes from is I'm trying to duplicate the task action in AzureDevOps pipeline [AzureAppServiceManage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-manage?view=azure-devops) task where when implemented successfully it stop/start all continuous webjobs. Azure CLI only stop/start one webjob at a time.

I need to capture the output from: `az webapp webjob continuous list`

The output is an array of hases that contain the webjob name.
`[{ "name": "vapp-name/webjob-name",}]`
Then split the value into returning and array of webjob-names

Example: `[webjob-name, webjob-name2, webjob-name 3]`

```
- name: Azure CLI script
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.0.72
        inlineScript: |
          az account show
          
          az webapp webjob continuous list --name "app-name" --resource-group resource-group-name
          az webapp webjob continuous start --name "app-name" --resource-group resource-group-name --subscription "Enterprise Subscription"
```

After much trial and error Working solution:

```
WEB_JOBS="$(az webapp webjob continuous list --name "name-app" --resource-group "name-resource-group" --subscription "Azure Subscription" --query "[].name" --output tsv)"
echo "$WEB_JOBS" | while read line ; do
  web_job_name="${line##*/}"
  az webapp webjob continuous start --name "name-app" --resource-group "name-resource-group" --subscription "Azure Subscription" --slot "slot-name" --webjob-name "$web_job_name"
done
```

Comment: What's the problem? Do you want to split the value into returning an array of webjob-names?

Comment: az cli doesn't have a flag/command to stop/start all webjobs which differs from the Azure App Service Manage pipeline task. I'll update to include the task.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
WEB_JOBS="$(az webapp webjob continuous list --name "name-app" --resource-group "name-resource-group" --subscription "Azure Subscription" --query "[].name" --output tsv)"
echo "$WEB_JOBS" | while read line ; do
  web_job_name="${line##*/}"
  az webapp webjob continuous start --name "name-app" --resource-group "name-resource-group" --subscription "Azure Subscription" --slot "slot-name" --webjob-name "$web_job_name"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure CLI to strat azure web job, we cannot start all azure web job at one time and we need to start the web job one by one. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/webjob?view=azure-cli-latest).

For example

```
res=$(az webapp webjob continuous list --name <>--resource-group <>--query '[].{name:name}' --output json)
for row in $(echo "${res}" | jq -r '.[].name'); do
   
    name=$(echo $row | cut -d'/' -f2)
    az webapp webjob continuous start --webjob-name $name --name <> --resource-group <>
done
```